# Linux Kernel Module - nfilter hook incorrect data on Slackware

Tags: c, tcp, kernel, slackware

I have a linux kernel module that needs to process the data received via netfilter hook as a socket buffer.

The data received on Debian 8 (kernel: 3.16.0) is good but with SlackWare 14.0 (kernel: 3.2.29) the data is incorrect. I do not understand what's wrong. I searched everywhere on the forum and on Google but I never found a solution.

This is my nfilter hook function:

```
static unsigned int magic_packet_hook(const struct nf_hook_ops *ops, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)) {
struct iphdr *iph;
struct tcphdr *tcph;

//Return if empty
if(!skb)
    return NF_ACCEPT;

//Get ip header
iph = ip_hdr(skb);

//Check protocol
if(iph->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
    return NF_ACCEPT;

//Get tcp header
tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);

//Get & check data
char *data;
data = (char *)((unsigned char *)tcph+(tcph->doff*4));
if(!data)
    return NF_ACCEPT;

//Print in dmesg
#ifdef DEBUG
    printk("anhackit data: %s\n", data);
#endif

//Convert source ip to string
char ip[16];
snprintf(ip, 16, "%pI4", &iph->saddr);

//Convert destination port to string
char port[6];
sprintf(port, "%u", ntohs(tcph->dest));

#ifdef DEBUG
    printk("anhackit - magic packet received from %s on port %s !\n", ip, port);
#endif

return NF_ACCEPT;}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just guessing, `data = (char *)((unsigned char *)tcph+(tcph->doff*4));` looks suspicious.

Comment: This is a magic packet handler for a rootkit.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand where you're going. Is it because I convert unsigned char* to char* ?

Comment: Well you said the data is incorrect. Not just those casts but also `*4` but as I said I was guessing. Since it is supposed to be "magic" which is not working perhaps there is some frog pretending to be a prince.

Comment: Perhaps you should define [in explicit detail] what you mean by "good" and "incorrect" (i.e.) expected behavior and actual behavior in both cases.

Comment: I know I'm doing something wrong but i don't understrand what, otherwise I would never have asked a question on this forum. So do you know what's the correct way to get the data from a sk_buff?

Comment: When I send a TCP packet with the command "nping --tcp -c 1 --dest-ip 127.0.0.1 -p 8888 --data-string "test"

The result in dmesg on Debian is "anhackit data: test"
But on SlackWare the result is "anhackit data: <something wrong>"

Comment: Nothing explicit. But, can `tcp_hdr` return NULL? If so, `data =`/`if (! data)` is not a sufficient test because you've already deref'ed the pointer (i.e.) you'd need `if (!tcph)` instead. I'd dump the data in hex as well and then decode by hand to see things

Comment: Sorry my english is not very good and I have difficulties to explain my problem. Ok thank you, I will try by replacing !data by !tcph

Comment: I looked at some kernel code and I believe `tcp_hdr` can _not_ be null because it returns an offset pointer from `skb`. So, your `if (!data)` isn't required. You have `printk` for the data. What does it print on the "good" system and the "incorrect" system? Edit your question and post this. Otherwise, what makes Slackware incorrect? Does it _not_ print anything? Or, does it print bad data? `data` may or may not be EOS terminated, so you may want to handle that. You probably need to get the payload length (e.g. for your `"test"`, it would be 4 or 5 in the receiver, so find that value)

Comment: Since I changed !data by !tcph, I don't have any warnings in the dmesg. That's a good thing so I think !tcph is not useless and thank you for this recommendation. Slackware display bad data (not readable). I will try to retrieve the size of the payload.

Comment: Look at `include/linux/tcp.h` and `include/linux/skbuff.h`. Try to understand more about the structs. Also, consider looking at other working code in the kernel source tree. Try to find a similar filter module and use that as a guide.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. I post the solution if I find it.